# CSS Positioning a tall element across two rows without using "grid" or "flexbox"

Tags: html, css

I'm making a calculator app for my freeCodeCamp certification. I have been trying to replicate their style without inspecting their code to challenge myself, but I ran into this issue:

[image: This is how their calculator looks]

In their calculator, the "EQUALS" button is twice as tall as the other buttons. I tried to replicate it, but mine ends up looking like this:

[image]

The keys following the equals key get shifted to a new line. I consulted the freeCodeCamp code and they seem to be using `position: absolute` to fix this. However, in my project, the same value does this instead:

[image]

I understand why that is - `position: absolute` removes the equals button from the document flow, and the other buttons centre themselves on their rows as a result. What I'm curious is how would i go about fixing these positions. I thought about using a CSS grid, but I want to figure out how they made this work in the first place.

**Edit:** I understand I can use grid or flexbox to accomplish my goal. What I'm trying to figure out, however, is how freeCodeCamp accomplished this design without using either.

I also replaced the JSX and SCSS with plain HTML + CSS so the snippet can be ran.

```css
.Calculator {
  position: relative;
  background-color: black;
  border: 2px solid #777;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 320px;
}

.calcKey {
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 65px;
  background-color: #4d4d4d;
  border: none;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  cursor: default;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.calcKey:hover {
  outline: 1px solid #777;
  z-index: 1;
  color: black;
}

.calcKeyMath {
    background-color: #666666;
}

.calcKeyAC {
    background-color: #ac3939;
}

.calcKeyEquals {
  background-color: #004466;
  position: absolute;
}

.calcKeyWide {
  width: 160px;
}

.calcKeyTall {
  height: 130px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Calculator">
  <div class="calcKeysContainer">
    <button class="calcKey calcKeyWide calcKeyAC" id="clear" value="clear">AC</button>
    <button class="calcKey calcKeyMath" id="divide" value="divide">/</button>
    <button class="calcKey calcKeyMath" id="multiply" value="multiply">x</button>
    <button class="calcKey" id="seven" value="7">7</button>
    <button class="calcKey" id="eight" value="8">8</button>
    <button class="calcKey" id="nine" value="9">9</button>
    <button class="calcKey calcKeyMath" id="subtract" value="subtract">-</button>
    <button class="calcKey" id="four" value="4">4</button>
    <button class="calcKey" id="five" value="5">5</button>
    <button class="calcKey" id="six" value="6">6</button>
    <button class="calcKey calcKeyMath" id="add" value="add">+</button>
    <button class="calcKey" id="one" value="1">1</button>
    <button class="calcKey" id="two" value="2">2</button>
    <button class="calcKey" id="three" value="3">3</button>
    <button class="calcKey calcKeyTall calcKeyEquals" id="equals" value="equals">=</button>
    <button class="calcKey calcKeyWide" id="zero" value="0">0</button>
    <button class="calcKey" id="." value=".">.</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you haven't looked at their code, how can you be sure they aren't using these techniques?